# Can't deploy a function in Firebase which include @google-cloud/storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a function in firebase cloud functions to be triggered when a new file is uploaded in the storage.

I've included the google-cloud/storage lib to manage some download but it seems there's an error in the lib preventing me to deploy :

> node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service-object.d.ts(72,45): error TS8020: JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service-object.d.ts(72,45): error TS8028: JSDoc '...' may only appear in the last parameter of a signature.
>
> node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.d.ts(291,55): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

Does anyone face the same issue ? any workaround ? downgrade lib to older version or newer for TypeScript ?

Thanks,
Nanex

Comment: What version are you using?  I'm using the latest 2.3.3 with TypeScript without these problems.

Comment: Was using the latest version at the time I wrote this question, I since rollback to an older version that's working fine for me :(